# Initializing class instance with curly braces

Tags: c++, class, struct, initialization

I am aware struct and class in C++ are very similar and struct members are by default having public access, while class members having private access and so on..etc.

However, since struct instances can be initialized like this:

```
struct MyStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

MyStruct s1 = {1, 2, 3};  //a=1, b=2, c=3
MyStruct s2 = {};  //a=0, b=0, c=0
```

Is it safe to do the same for classes in C++? For example:

```
class MyClass{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

MyClass c1 = {1, 2, 3};  //a=1, b=2, c=3
MyClass c2 = {};  //a=0, b=0, c=0
```

**Question**: I am aware we can use constructor(s), is there any pitfalls I should be aware of if I initialize class instance like struct instances? Is this a safe operation if I use this approach to initialize the data members to its default values (e.g. 0 for int and null for pointers)?

Comment: In C++ there is no difference between a class and struct except for the default access specifier.

Comment: @NathanOliver So can I assume it is safe to initialize class instances using the curly braces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only difference between `struct` and `class` is the default access specification: `MyClass` has three `private` members and `MyStruct` has three `public` ones. As a result, `MyClass` is **not** an aggregate (one of the requirements is that a class have no private or protected non-static data members), which makes this code ill-formed:

```
MyClass c1 = {1, 2, 3};  // error
```

But there is no difference between your initialization of `MyStruct` and what your initialization of `MyClass` would have been had you made the members all `public`.

Comment: Oh good point.  I missed the OP didn't use `public:` in the class.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for your reply. So, if all data members of MyClass were public, I could simply initialize them with `= {1,2,3};` without much worries?

Comment: @user3437460 Yes, as stated in the answer, there would be no difference.